# How to get POST contents before form submits using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, url, post

So, I know that when I submit a form whose method is POST that the server receives the contents of that form and then processes them accordingly, and then returns a page with the desired content. What I am trying to learn is what exact query url is being passed to the server side script when I submit a form on a website that does not belong to me. The reason I want this query string is so that I can make use of the server side script programatically with my own data. There is no public API served by this website, but I would like to formulate my own.

**So my question is, is there a way to intercept the POST as a query string URL? Perhaps by using a javascript console in browser?**

I know I can look at the source code for the page and find the names/values of the form fields. However, there also happens to be a hidden field on this page whose properties are set by javascript during validation at submission time. How should I go about this?

Comment: Use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and you'll see exactly what the URL for the requests look like.

Comment: You can use jQuery to `$.serialize($('form'))` to get the serialized post string. In fact, the first example here looks like what you're trying to do: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: If you're wanting to intercept it in the BROWSER, you can use FireBug for FireFox, or Inspector in Google Chrome

Comment: @adeneo - that looks like an awesome tool - I will certainly be trying it out in the near future. However, I didn't realize chrome already had the built in functionality until Rob W pointed it out. From the developer console just navigate to the network tab, then run the submission and you can view the url as submitted. Thanks for the JQuery solution too. Good work gentleman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extension for intercept the data : Tamper Data on FireFox

https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

You can intercept and modify all headers requests

Comment: Thanks, have a look at the answers in the comments too everybody, those were great.